# Setting JDK & ANT in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, ant, java-8

In my Eclipse IDE, I'm interested in setting my default JDK & ANT to the one's I have installed on my machine(Windows 8.1 64x).  Can anyone provide reasons why I may or may not want to do this, & how it would be done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for ant, you will usually be fine using the one that is embedded in eclipse.

As for the JDK (I am assuming you are talking about the one that is running your programs, not the one that runs eclipse), in my opinion you really need to control what JDK you are using, for example to match the one that will be used in production. And actually if I remember correctly eclipse will not use one you haven't added yourself.

You can add JREs in the preferences (*Window / Preferences*), in *Java / Installed JREs*. Click *Add* and browse to where your JDK is installed.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

It looks like I can choose from: Standard VM, Standard 1.1.x VM, Execution Environment Description.

suggestions?

Comment: Standard VM will be fine.